# Polynomials - The sum of two roots

Tags: polynomials, roots

If the sum of two roots of
$$x^4  + 2x^3 - 8x^2 - 18x - 9 = 0$$ is
$0$, find
the roots of the equation

Comment: Try using the rational roots test to get some roots for free. If there were any rational roots, they would have to divide 9, so $\pm 1$, $\pm 3$, $\pm 9$.

Comment: So you just test each root to make it equal zero.

Therefore
(x - 1) (x + 3) (x - 3) = 0

Answer is x= 1, -3, + 3

Comment: I'm not sure what your comment means.  But $x=1$ is not a root, and $x=-1$ is.

Comment: i meant the factors. not the roots

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Generally, if there's two roots whose sum is zero, then it means that two factors are $x-a$ and $x+a$, which means that $x^2-a^2$ must be a factor. So clearly
$$
(x^2-a^2)(x^2+bx+c)=x^4+2x^3-8x^2-18x-9=0
$$
Find the values of $a^2$, $b$, and $c$ that satisfy the left equality, and you'll have found factors that you can then solve for all roots. (This works even if there's no rational root)

Comment: Very helpful, but one thing to clear it up, it's always a guess and check method to find a,b and c. there is no other way to find the roots otherwise? except for the certain relativism between the factors and roots.

Comment: Not true. You know that $b-a^2=2$, that $a^2c=9$, and that $a^2b=18$. These can be easily solved for the factors, and then you merely need to check that they satisfy the $x^2$ term.

Comment: Oh ok thank you very much. Makes sense.

Comment: @MATHSUSER Another way to see it is that because $x^2-a^2$ only has even-power terms, the odd and even-power parts of $x^4 + 2x^3 - 8x^2 - 18x - 9$ must be separately divisible by $x^2-a^2$.  In particular, $x^2 - a^2$ divides $2x^3 - 18x = 2x(x^2-9)$.  (Or just observe that comparing $x^3$ terms tells you $b = 2$.)

Answer (score 6):

Hints:

The constant coefficient (constant term) is $-9$.

$$\pm 1, \pm 3\pm 9 \;\text{divide}\; -9 $$

If there are rational roots to the polynomial, they will be among these values. $\large (\star)$

Two of the roots  $x_i, x_j$ be must be factors of $-9$: and they must be such that $x_i = -x_j$. Lets call this pair $a, \pm a$. That means $(x−a)$ and $x-(-a) = (x + a)$ will be factors of the polynomial.

Now, what do we get when we multiply $(x+a)(x-a)$?

---

$(\large \star)$ Why do we know this? See the [Rational Root Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem), where you'll see why, and where you'll find **additional** tremendously useful things to know when you need to factor a polynomial (and you learn how to tell whether or not **any** rational roots exist!)

Comment: Cong! for the gold medal. I mean the new one. I see another is one the way. ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Hint: $x^4+2x^3+x^2-9(x^2+2x+1)=x^2(x+1)^2-9(x+1)^2=(x^2-9)(x+1)^2$.

Answer (score 2):

I'd do it this way. If $x=\pm a$ are roots of the equation, then $f(x)=x^2-a^2$ is a factor of the polynomial. Note that this contains only even powers of $x$.

Now suppose we multiply $f(x)$ by another polynomial $p(x)$ so that $f(x)p(x)=P(x)$. Let e(x) be the polynomial obtained by picking out the even powers of $p(x)$ with $o(x)$ as the odd powers, so that $p(x)=e(x)+o(x)$ and $$f(x)p(x)=f(x)e(x)+f(x)o(x)=E(x)+O(x)=P(x)$$ gives a decomposition of $P(x)$ into the sum of even powers of $x$ plus the sum of odd powers of $x$, with $f(x)$ a factor of both $E(x)$ and $O(x)$.

In brief, we know that, in the case presented $$x^4-8x^2-9$$ and$$2x^3-18x$$

have a common factor of the kind we are seeking. In a more complex example we could use the Euclidean algorithm to pin this down further (there might be other common factors). But here the even and odd parts are easy to factorise as $$(x^2-9)(x^2+1)$$ (treat this as a quadratic in $x^2$) and$$2x(x^2-9)$$

From there we can easily finish the factorisation.

Note: this is an entirely systematic approach, which simplifies the problem without having to guess.

Note: this is essentially the approach suggested by Erick Wong in a comment on another answer, which I spotted after I had written this all out.

Comment: I think this approach is too complicated, for a question that is fairly simple.

Comment: @MATHSUSER I think this is a very simple approach - I explained it at length - but look at what I had to do, and how picking out the odd part gives the factor you want almost immediately and at sight. I put it at length, just to show that it would also work in more complicated cases. It would work for a factor $x^2-8$, when the rational root test would fail. And the question does not imply that the roots in question are rational.

Comment: @MATHSUSER I noted that the answer you accepted gave a factorisation, and said find $a^2, b, c$. What you end up doing with that is a complicated way of getting to this same place. I was looking for an observation which would simplify the problem and reduce the amount of work.

Comment: I'm not criticizing your answer by any means.

Comment: @MATHSUSER I thought you may have misunderstood it

Answer (score 1):

Let those two roots be $a,-a$ and the other two roots are $b,c$

$$\text{Now, }(x-a)(x+a)(x-b)(x-c)=(x^2-a^2)\{x^2-(b+c)x+bc\}$$
$$=x^4-x^3(b+c)+(bc-a^2)x^2+a^2(b+c)x-a^2bc$$

Comparing the coefficients of $x^3$ of this with that of $x^4  + 2x^3 - 8x^2 - 18x - 9 = 0,$

$b+c=-2$

Comparing the coefficients of $x,a^2(b+c)=-18\implies 2a^2=18\implies a=\pm3$

Comparing the  constants, $a^2bc=9\implies bc=1$

So, $b,c$ are the roots of the equation $t^2-(-2)t+(1)=0\implies t=-1,-1$